# PHP file access on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, file-access

I am developing a PHP project.  To date, this has involved modifying the files locally, uploading to my web site and testing the change.  This gets tedious.

To make development faster, I have configured Apache to point localhost at the relevant local directory, so I can simply change the file and refresh the browser.  This mostly works as expected.

However, whenever I attempt to check for a file which may not exist (a necessary part of the project), the PHP interpreter simply stops.  "file_exists(filename)" is simply not executed, and nothing more happens, although everything up to that point in the script functions fine.

I have searched online for a solution several times, but nobody else seems to have hit this issue.  Presumably I have some kind of permission conflict?  Any suggestions for a solution or workaround? Many thanks.

I expect "file_exists(filename)" to work as expected.

Instead, it seems to crash the PHP interpreter.

Comment: You need to enable full error reporting and either configure everything so errors are shown (recommended for your local environment) or check the error logs for messages. There's an overview [here](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) for the PHP part. In the case of Apache, everything should be being logged already.

Comment: The other thing is check that your Dev environmant has not had Error Reporting turned off. So when code get to LIVE it has had all the errors fixed and not ignored